# MongoDB Geospatial queries in php

Tags: php, mongodb, geospatial

I'm trying to use MongDBs 2d indexing to run geospatial queries, as outlined here - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

It's working fine, and I'm able run queries such as

```
db.places.find( { point : { $near : [151.1955562233925,-33.87107475181752]  , $maxDistance : 0.1/111} } )
```

from the CLI tool, but when I try and run the query in PHP (using the PECL mongo driver) I'm not able to get any results.

Any help with how to write the above query for PHP? Does anyone know if the PHP driver supports geospatial queries?

Thanks

Comment: Hey I am trying to do something similar. Can you tell me what unit the maxDistace you have specified is. Is it kilometers or miles and why is it being divided by 111.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have geo lookup with the PHP driver working in production. It looks something like this:

```
$latLong = $geo->lookupLatLong($address);
$cursor = $coats->find(Array('latLong' => Array('$near' => $latLong)))->limit(10);
```

Also, you might want to consider using **$nearSphere** as opposed to $near to get more accurate coordinates. See [the mongo docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-TheEarthisRoundbutMapsareFlat) for more information.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I got it working with this. It's a shame that the simple JSON query in mongo becomes so verbose in php

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation in [MongoDB website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)

`{
  $near: {
     $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
     },
     $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
     $minDistance: <distance in meters>
  }
}`

The php code for the above query would be:

```
$query = array(
                'loc' => array(
                    '$near' => array(
                        '$geometry' =>array(
                            'type' => 'Point',
                            'coordinates'=>array(floatval($lon),floatval($lat)),
                            '$maxDistance' => intval($max_distance),
                            '$mixDistance' => intval($min_distance)))));
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of using the $nearSphere command in PHP would look something like:

```
$lonlat = array($lon, $lat);
$cursor = $this->collection->find(Array('loc' => Array('$nearSphere' => $lonlat)))->limit($limit);
```

Where 'loc' is the 2d geospatial index and limit is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try the exact PHP port for your mongo query.

```
$collection->find(Array("point" => Array('$within' => Array('$center'=> Array(Array(151.1955562233925,-33.87107475181752), 0.1/111 ) ) )));
```

Please make sure you typecast the lat-longs with float. Or else mongo extension will treat it as a string (surprise, surprise) and query will return assuming empty condition (this took forever me to find).

**EDIT**: Have a look at Cakephp mongo driver source for more ways to use geo queries. https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/master/samples/controllers/geos_controller.php

Comment: +1 for typecasting note. That was a troublesome little detail.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have success using 'near' as a part of find condition in PHP either.

You may use MongoDb geoNear command instead:

```
$db->command(array('geoNear'=>'places','near'=>array(151.1955562233925,-33.87107475181752),'num'=>9));
```