# Incorrect sort result when using $nearSphere

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

this sorted correctly when using directly

```
db.users.find({currentloc : {$nearSphere : [115.22804,-8.69914]}})
```

but when execute from PHP, it look like sorted by _id

```
$users = $this->m->mappt->users;
$results = $users->find(
    array(
        'currentloc' => array('$nearSphere' => array(115.22804,-8.69914))

    );
$arrayresult = iterator_to_array($results);
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine. I can think of a few things:

- You don't have a `2dsphere` index, which you do have from the shell
- `iterator_to_array()` is messing with it — if you do a normal `foreach()` do you get them in the right order then?

Comment: Thanks, it looks Laravel 4 Response::json() screw up array position. using both iterator_to_array() and foreach() outside Laravel just worked fine. Thanks for the pointer though

Answer (score 0):

Adi, You can get idea from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347783/mongodb-geospatial-queries-in-php). You can try to use variable name for **geo** values.

Other try like this,

```
$collection->find(Array("point" => Array('$within' => Array('$center'=> Array(Array(151.1955562233925,-33.87107475181752), 0.1/111 ) ) )));
```